# Proof of proposition 16.2 on page 56 of G. Bredon's topology and geometry

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

In proposition 16.2 of page 56 in Bredon's topology and geometry the statement reads that if $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed convex subset and 0 is an interior point of $C$ then any ray from the origin intersects the boundary of $C$ in at most one point.
The idea of the proof is as follows: If $R$ is a ray from origin then consider $0\neq p,q; p\neq q; p,q\in R \cap C$ further assume, $\lVert p \rVert < \lVert q \rVert$. Since 0 is an interior point there is an open ball $B$ around 0 inside $C$. Taking the union of the line segments joining point in $B$ and $q$ the author shows that $p$ is an interior point of the union of the segments and hence an interior point of $C$.

I am unable to prove $p$ is an interior point of the union of the segments. Any hint of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the radius of the ball around 0 contained in $C$ to be $R$. Choose $r= (1- \lambda)R$ where $p=\lambda q$ hence $0<\lambda <1$.

For a point $x=p+ \epsilon u $ where $u$ is a unit vector and $\epsilon <r$ consider the vector $y=\frac{\epsilon}{1-\lambda}u \in B(0,R) $. It is easy to check that $x$ lies on the line segment joining $y, q$.

Comment: Good work! Your proof is valid, I checked.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the assumption $p,q \in R \cap C$: This means that $p$ and $q$ both still lie on the ray $R$, but the part of the ray $R$ which connects $p,q$ with $0$ is definitely a subset (or think "sub-ray") of the cone that you described, since this cone contains all rays that connect points in $B$ with $q$, and 0 is a point in $B$. Then, because $\|p\| < \|q\|$, you get that $p$ must lie in the interior of $C$. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can it be shown using some open ball argument? It is geometrically clear to me. I was trying to figure out some rigorous proof. I might be missing something.

Comment: I'm guessing you could define the cone more rigorously, and then you could argue more precisely why $R \in$ cone. I suppose a good place to start would be $\mathbb{R}^2$. But other than that, I don't think you should put too much effort into a fully rigorous proof, as often times with these kinds of questions it suffices to give a geometric sketch.

Comment: can you check my solution below?